# How to Set Up Tensorflow GPU on Windows 11?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I was trying to set up GPU to be compatible with Tensorflow on Windows 11 but was encountering a problem when attempting to verify that it had been setup correctly. I have a GPU driver installed and ran the following command in Miniconda under the 'tf' environment as suggested by step 5 of the Tensorflow installation instructions for Windows Native (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows-native):

```
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0
However, when I go to check that the GPU has been setup correctly, I encounter the following message:
2022-12-27 01:05:04.628568: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-12-27 01:05:04.628893: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2022-12-27 01:05:06.913025: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-12-27 01:05:06.913317: W 

~and then after several other lines of similar error messages~

tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2022-12-27 01:05:06.915294: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1934] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
[]
```

I can't figure out what is wrong, given that I've merely followed the Tensorflow installation steps. Any ideas on what the problem could be or what I should try next?

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure you have checked the mentioned **Hardware requirements** and **Software requirements** in the same link to enable GPU support. Also [set the path](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#set_your_path) to the bin directory after installing these software.

Now, follow the Step-by-step instructions to install TensorFlow with GPU setup after installing conda

```
conda create --name tf python=3.9
conda activate tf

conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install "tensorflow-gpu<2.11"
```

to verify the GPU setup:

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

Comment: I am getting the error 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow<2.11 (from versions: 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1, 2.13.0rc2, 2.13.0, 2.13.1, 2.14.0rc0, 2.14.0rc1, 2.14.0, 2.14.1, 2.15.0rc0, 2.15.0rc1, 2.15.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow<2.11